# Default Kubernetes Pod Memory Usage?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I defined a StatefulSet that has a container inside that it launches. CPU limits and requests are listed, however I never specified the same for memory. I have pods running now but I don't know how much memory they're taking. It's too much whatever it is so I want to lower it. How do I find out what it is?

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can check the pods ressources usage by executing this command:

```sh
kubectl top po
```

also  you can specify the container usage inside your pods if you have more than one container inside your pods:

```sh
kubectl top po --containers
```

also if you have a kubecrnetes dashboard it will be more easy .

Answer (score 0):

`...I don't know how much memory they're taking`

You can install [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#installation) in your cluser and use `kubectl top pod` command to find out.